# r - Project Euler 40: getting the final digit wrong

Tags: r, debugging

> An irrational decimal fraction is created by concatenating the
>   positive integers:
>
> 0.12345678910**1**112131415161718192021...
>
> It can be seen that the 12th digit of the fractional part is 1.
>
> If dn represents the nth digit of the fractional part, find the value
>   of the following expression.
>
> d1 × d10 × d100 × d1000 × d10000 × d100000 × d1000000

Problem source [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=40).

I wrote the following code to calculate the digits:

```
ans = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow=2))
colnames(ans) = c(10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000)
rownames(ans) = c("length","number")

counter = 1
for(i in c(10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000))
{
  c = 0
  num = 0

  while (c<i)
  {
    num = num + 1
    c = c + nchar(as.character(num))
  }

  ans[1, counter] = c
  ans[2, counter] = num

  counter = counter + 1 
}
```

The output, is:

```
> ans
       10 100 1000 10000  1e+05   1e+06
length 11 101 1002 10001 100004 1000004
number 10  55  370  2777  22222  185185
```

In other words, when the irrational number is 11 digit long, its final two digits are `10`, which means its 10th digit is `1`. When the irrational number is 1002 digits long, its final three digits are 370, which means its 1000th digit is `3`. And so on.

From this, the answer I get is: 1 * 1 * 5 * 3 * 7 * 2 * **8**. However, the correct answer is 1 * 1 * 5 * 3 * 7 * 2 * **1**. It just beats me how it is able to produce correct answers until the final digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method gives the correct answer if you force all your calculations to be with integer arithmetic - just add `L` to all numbers: `c=0L`, `num=num+1L`, etc.

It goes wrong at the point where `num=100000` and `c=488894 or 488895`.  Without the integer arithmetic, it is using the character string `"1e+05"` instead of `"100000"`, which is one character shorter. `100001` and later are not affected. Setting `options(scipen=99)` will stop it doing this.

Answer (score 2):

It took a while to figure out what you're trying to do there. I think you have an interesting approach, however I also think the easiest way to do it, is to get a sequence of `1, 2, 3, ... 10, 11, ... 10000, 10001, 10002 ...` and collapse it into one string. Then you can take the character number `1, 10, 100, ..., 1.000.000` using `substr`:

```
vec  <- paste(1:500000, collapse = "")
inds <- 10^(0:6)

digits <- sapply(inds, function(x) substr(vec, x, x))
# [1] "1" "1" "5" "3" "7" "2" "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution on Python:

```
from functools import reduce

def elems_total(elem1, elem2):
    return elem1 * elem2

# store the values
fraction = ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1,1000000)])
total = 1

# get [0, 9, 99 ... 999999]
digits_only_9 = [x for x in range(0, 1000000) if x % 9 == 0 and \
                 len(set(str(x))) == 1 and \
                 str(x).endswith('9')]

summa = reduce(elems_total, [int(fraction[i]) for i in digits_only_9])
print(summa)  # 210
```